# IBM ICP Installation - Docker "run" Command Error

Tags: docker, rhel, ibm-cloud-private

I'm trying to instal IBM Cloud Private - Cloud Native Edition 2.0.1.2 on a RHEL machine. However, I'm running into an error on Docker on step two of installation.

When I'm trying to run the below command

```
sudo docker run -v $(pwd):/data -e LICENSE=accept \
 ibmcom/icp-inception:2.1.0.2-ee \
 cp -r cluster /data
```

And I'm getting an error saying console flag is not defined with a description below:

```
    Incorrect usage.
flag provided but not defined: -console
NAME:
    docker-runc create - create a container
USAGE:
    docker-runc create [command options] <container-id>

Where "<container-id>" is your name for the instance of the container that you are starting. The nae you provide for the container instance must be unique on your host.

DESCRIPTION:
    The create command creates an instance of a container for a bundle. The bundle is a directory with a specification
    file named "config.json" and a root filesystem.

    The specification file includes an args parameter. The args parameter is used to specify command(s) that get run when the container is started.
    To change the command(s) that get executed on start, edit the args parameter of the spec. See "runc spec --help" for more explanation.

OPTIONS:
    --bundle value, -b value    path to the root of the bundle directory, defaults to the current directory.
    --console-socket value      path to an AF_UNIX socket which will receive a file descriptor referencing the master end of the console's pseudoterminal
    --pid-file value            specify the file to write the process id to
    --no-pivot                  do not use pivot root to jail process inside rootfs. This should be used whenever the rootfs is on top of a ramdisk
    --no-new-keyring            do not create a new session keyring for the container. This will cause the container to inherit the calling processes session
    --preserve-fds value        Pass N additional file descriptors to the container(stdio + $LISTEN_FDS + N in total) (default: 0)

/usr/bin/docker-current: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: flag provided but not defined: -console.
ERRO{0000] error getting events from daemon: net/http: request canceled
```

As you can see, it's also mentioning it cannot get events from net/http daemon. I'm using Docker 1.13 version.

Is my firewall blocking something or is there something I need to fix on RHEL? I have installed ICP on Ubuntu machines many times without a problem. This is a different machine working on a different environment.

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you install icp-docker-17.09_x86_64.bin ? If you used the package at Docker or from yum, for RHEL, thats no good.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSBS6K_2.1.0.2/supported_system_config/supported_docker.html